# How can I export contacts and tags, but only for a particular tag?

Tags: export, tags

Is it possible to export contacts and related Tag information, but only for one particular Tag Set? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can export tags for contacts with a particular tag. It doesn't seem you can export just one particular tag, but you could easily do this as a post-process once you've exported to CSV.

Checked on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ -

- Search => Advanced Search
- "Basic Criteria" group => Tags => Volunteer
- Submit "Search"
- Click "All 61 Records"
- Select "Export records" action
- Export PRIMARY fields
- Exported CSV contains tag information ...